.Net8 Isolated FunctionApp not showing up in Azure after deployment
FunctionApp works fine when deployed from Visual Studio using the downloaded publish profile from Azure. But when I try to deploy from Gitlab using ci/cd pipeline, the FunctionApp is not displayed in Azure.
I downloaded the app content from Azure portal for both deployments and compared the folders. I could find the exe in the app content that was published from Visual Studio but code deployed by Gitlab pipeline compiled to dll.
For some reason OutputType Exe setting in the project file is being ignored by the Gitlab pipeline.
After migrating FunctionApps to isolated model, I updated the git.yml file to use mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 image and these are the commands to build/publish

dotnet build $SLN_PATH -c Release -v d
dotnet publish $SLN_PATH -o ./out -c Release

The FunctionApp was working fine with in-process model and sdk:6.0 image for both deployments (from Visual Studio using publish profile & Gitlab pipeline). Not sure if anything chaged in sdk:8.0 image.
How can I make it publish an exe instead of dll?
Visual Studio compiling to exe but gitlab pipeline is producing a dll
gitlab yml file

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
    GIT_PROJECT_CLONE: 'https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/xyz/functionApp-net8.git --branch main'
    DOTNET_PUBLISH_ARGS: "${DOTNET_BUILD_ARGS} /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=${PROFILE_NAME}"
    BUILD_ARTIFACTS: "./src/**/bin/**"
    NUGET_PACKAGES: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.nugetcache"
    DOTNET_BUILD_ARGS: "-c Release -v d"
    AZURE_CLIENT_ID: "xyz"
    AZURE_RESOURCE_TYPE: "azure_functions"
    AZURE_CLI_PARAMS: "--verbose"

build:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
    stage: build
    script:
      - 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip'
      - |
        if [ -z "${GIT_PROJECT_CLONE}" ] ; then
          echo "[INFO] GIT_PROJECT_CLONE not set, skip clone"
        else  
          echo "[INFO] GIT_PROJECT_CLONE is set , do clone ${GIT_PROJECT_CLONE}"
          cd ..
          git clone $GIT_PROJECT_CLONE
          ls -lart
          cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR
        fi
      - |
        if [ -z "${SLN_PATH}" ] ; then
          echo "[INFO] SLN_PATH not set, searching for .sln"
          SLN_PATH=`find . -type f -regex ".*\.sln"`
        fi
        echo "[INFO] SLN_PATH set to ${SLN_PATH}."
        dotnet build $SLN_PATH $DOTNET_BUILD_ARGS
        echo "[INFO] DOTNET_PUBLISH_ARGS set to ${DOTNET_PUBLISH_ARGS}."
        echo "[INFO] actual dotnet publish ${SLN_PATH} ${DOTNET_PUBLISH_ARGS}"
        dotnet publish $SLN_PATH -o ./out -c Release
        ls -lart
        cd $OUT_FOLDER
        ls -lart
        zip -r ../out.zip *
        cd ..
        ls -lart
        cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - $OUT_FOLDER
        - $OUT_FOLDER.zip
      expire_in: 1 week
    cache:
      key: "$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
      paths:
        - .nugetcache
    rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
      when: never
    - when: on_success

.deploy:
  stage: deploy
  id_tokens:
    CI_JOB_JWT:
      aud: "vault"
  secrets:
    AZURE_PASSWORD:
      vault: AZURE_PASSWORD@xyz
  variables:
    AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: "xyz"
    AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION: "xyz"
    AZURE_TENANTID: "xyz"
    AZURE_USERNAME: "xyz"
    AZURE_APP_NAME: "$AZURE_APP_NAME"
  extends: .azure_deploy
  environment: 
    name: test/azure/${AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP}/functionapp/${AZURE_APP_NAME}
    url: https://${AZURE_APP_NAME}.scm.azurewebsites.net
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
      when: never
    - when: on_success



Can you share your Gitlab yml file?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya added gitlab yml file

Below given .yml file worked for me.

zip the content of publish folder

stages:
  - Build
  - Deploy

variables:
    function_name: "csharpfunc6sep"
    Client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    Client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    tenant_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Build:
    stage: Build
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
    script: 
        - apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip
        - dotnet publish --configuration Release --output ./output
        - cd output
        - zip -r ../output.zip ./*

    artifacts:
        paths:
          - ./output.zip
        expire_in: 1 day
Deploy:
    stage: Deploy
    script:
        - curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
        - az login --service-principal -u $Client_id -p $Client_secret --tenant $tenant_id
        - az functionapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group Vivek-RG --name $function_name --src ./output.zip


    dependencies:
      - Build
    rules:
      - when: on_success


NOTE :- Node images with core-tools tag can also be used in Deploy stage like mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node20-core-tools for running az and func command as Azure CLI and Azure Function core tools are inbuilt in these images.


Currently func command support only net6.0 for dotnet-isolated during deployment using func.

OUTPUT:



